# Can I customize my project icon in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

Since I have only c++ projects in my solution, the standard '++' icon does not add any value.
[image]

It would be nice if I could assign a 'custom' icon to my project:

[image]

Do you know if there is a way?